# concurrency in tomcat/servlets

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, concurrency

I have been searching SO and the web and  I dont seem to find concrete example (or maybe just me not getting it). So maybe you guys can get me some help

I have created a survlet that extends HTTPREQUEST on TOMCAT 7. The doGet successfully access the file and do a long writing operation then returns the results to the requester.

Now my goal is to handle requests if they come at the same time. I.e queue them and execute one after the other.

Any idea how to do that? Any example to follow?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat will handle multiple incoming requests automatically. `server.xml` has a `maxThreads` value you can configure. Note there will be only one instance of the servlet, so be sure it doesn't have any shared state.

On a related note, you generally shouldn't have long running tasks on the request thread, but rather put the long running tasks on a separate thread. Servlet 3.0 allows for much easier asynchronous processing so the tomcat threads will free to handle more requests. If async processing in servlets is new to you, check out this introduction http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077995/java-concurrency/asynchronous-processing-support-in-servlet-3-0.html.

Comment: Thank you but as I said for every request I have to write to a file.  So the shared data is the file and as a result the concurrent requests will crash, no?

Comment: @Snake Sounds like you should be using a database instead. The response of your system when there are as few clients as two will be abominable.

Comment: I didn't realize you were writing to the SAME file. Queuing up requests like this is not a good idea as it completely defeats the purpose of having concurrent requests. You should rethink your design and consider what @EJP is saying and use a database that supports concurrency natively.

Comment: Thank you. But honestly, I am not planning to introduce a higher complexity into the solution. I can have up to 20 people hitting up the request at once and I want to the processing to be done in serial manner. Thus my orginal question, how can I queue them? Do I create a static Queue variable and access it (in a syncrohnized manner)?

Comment: You would have to synchronize state to do this, yes. Realize though that if the request threads take a long time, they may time out. So if you have a few queued up, it's possible that the ones later in the queue will throw a timeout error.